# Loop Optimization in python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, optimization

I have a dataframe **df** like this

```
Product Yr Value
A      2014 1
A      2015 3
A      2016 2
B      2015 2
B      2016 1
```

I want to do max cumululative ie

```
Product Yr Value
A      2014 1
A      2015 3
A      2016 3
B      2015 2
B      2016 2
```

My actual data has about **50000 products**
I am writing a code like:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame()
for i in (df['Product'].unique()):
    data3=df[df['Product']==i]
    data3.sort_values(by=['Yr'])
    data3['Value']=data3['Value'].cummax()
    df2=df2.append(data3)

#df2 is my result
```

This code is taking a lot of time(~3 days) for about 50000 products and 10 years. Is there some way to speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby.cummax` instead:

```
df['Value'] = df.sort_values('Yr').groupby('Product').Value.cummax()

df
#Product      Yr    Value
#0     A    2014    1
#1     A    2015    3
#2     A    2016    3
#3     B    2015    2
#4     B    2016    2
```

Comment: `groupby` is way faster than sorting unique values, then re-indexing into the df with `df[df[...]==i]` because the re-slice adds another O(n) step inside an already O(n) loop, making O(n^2). Additionally it passes control back to python very frequently instead of keeping the calls within the c library